# Getting an error inserting a timestamp using JDBC and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am new to PostgreSQL. I am trying to insert data to a table using JDBC.

One of the column values to be inserted are of following type.

> 2014-04-04T19:56:42.784Z  (Please note the T and Z in the string).

I first used `timestamp` as a datatype for corresponding column. However, I am getting the following ERROR :

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "T19"

I then changed it to `character(40)` thinking might be my format is wrong.  However, still getting the same error.

Later, when I removed the T and Z from the string, the error stopped. Also please note I also thought colon could be the problem. However, that is not the case through my testing.

Java code snippet

```
String line = 1,2014-04-04T19:56:42.784Z,456,0
String[] tempStr = strLine.split(",");
String sql = "INSERT INTO Table (A , TimeOfSess , B  , C )"
             + "VALUES("+tempStr[0]+","+tempStr[1]+","+tempStr[2]+","+tempStr[3]+")";

stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Please note I am using `TimeOfSess` as a `character(40)`. For my analysis it is not important to store the time as time. Character will also work. So I am going the easy way around here.

Comment: Please provide your java code responsible for inserting.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` and use `setTimestamp()`. Don't pass timestamp (or date) values as Strings

Comment: "*For my analysis it is not important to store the time as time*" - well your analysis is wrong. "*Character will also work*" - no it won't. **Always** use the correct data type. Storing dates, numbers or timestamps as varchar **will** get you in trouble.